# Stopping high contention objects being operated on simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am running a PHP app connecting to a MySQL database which at time has high load and high contention for certain actions.

Some actions are very important and two processess triggered at the same time by two different users sometimes need to be treated in a queue. Otherwise actions can happen twice which shouldn't.

How best with PHP and MySQL do you think I could overcome such issues?

Answer (score 1):

By using [MySQL transactions and/or locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html).

Comment: Could you give me an example of some code? I get the MySQL transactions part of it. But not sure how a PHP script may differ to allow graceful handling of this?

Comment: Hard to say exactly without knowing a lot more about your code. A lot depends on what level of transaction isolation you need, and how you want to handle conflicts. Having the scripts involved all open a transaction when they start and commit when they're finished will be a good start, though.

Comment: I can explain a scenario if that would help?